# Are my answers that I will give in the application going to be refused by UK visa officer?

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork, standard-visitor-visas, uk-citizens

I have planed to visit my cousin in England for 1 month and therefore I need to apply for a standard visitor visa. My cousin is a British citizen and he is sponsoring this trip for me. There are 3 questions on my application which I do not feel very sure if I am answering in the right way (I need any suggestions by you for example something that I should add to my answer... ):

**1- Why are they (my cousin in this case) helping to pay for your visit?**

My cousin and his family have been in Albania (country where I live) too many times, I have been very supportive to them and I have helped them to be more familiar in their holidays in Albania. My family also has been very kind to them in every situations and has helped them in any way they could so my cousin feels very thankful and wants to give it back by making my wish to once visit England come true. I really love their family and they really love me so they want me to visit them and to show me some of the most beautiful tourist places in the country they live in.

Documents that I am going to send with my applications by my cousin who is the sponsor of my trip:

- A photocopy of his passport
- A Bank statement of his income
- A letter
  of invitation by him (including that he has enough room for me and
  his home address)

**2- ....Do you have any suggestions of any other docs that I need by my cousin?**

**3- I have found some information that during the applications I should give the UK visa officer evidence that I am going to come back before visa ends.**

I am not sure what documents should I give to them to show evidence that I am coming back before my visa ends? I am 16 years old and I am still on a high school and I have planed to go to England at the end of this school year, after I finish this school year I have another two school years to finish my high school so I wouldn't interrupt my education because this is my future and I have good grades. Is it OK if I put in my other documents a verification that I am still a student? What other docs would be suitable to show that I am not going to stay in England.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documents I see that you definitely should include are:

- Your parents' [bank statements and proof of sources of income](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/66104/3221), and your own if you have your own bank account yet
- Proof that you are enrolled in high school

Comment: Should I include my parents bank statements even if my cousin is sponsoring everything for me?

Comment: The visa officer wants to see your own personal economic status, even if someone else pays all of your expenses. If your parents still take care of you, then they are part of that.

Comment: Can you tell me if I have answered the first question in the right way so will it be acceptable by visa officer

Comment: Yes, that's a fine answer.

Comment: thank you, if I will have another question I would be pleased to get an answer

Comment: Sorry I forgot something about the letter of invitation that my cousin will send to me, should it be a normal printed letter just with his signature or it should be something official for example a letter made at a notary?

Comment: You should also bring a permission letter from your parents to travel to the  UK. https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/if-youre-under-18

Comment: Please can I ask u for something? What happens if my parents don’t have any bank statements but only sources of income but they are a bit low and would not cover my expenses in england? My cousin is paying everything for me. Would the UK visa officer refuse my visa for this reason?

Comment: @Louis Your parents’ bank statements / pay slips etc are provided to show that they take care of you. This helps the UK ECO to understand your own personal circumstances in your home country. Your sponsor’s statements will be needed to show his/her capacity to financially support your visit. If your parents can’t show they are supporting you at home, the ECO may possibly see that as a negative ie a reason for you not to return.